# Bootstrap button group always align horizontally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Bootstrap button group make them always in one line, always align horizontally.
When I resize window button comes down vertically.

I am looking for a solution where button comes always in one line no matter what.

I have applied `style="white-space:nowrap;"` on parent div but it doesn't work.

***If possible try to use only bootstrap's inbuilt css classes.***
***Please answer by keeping current HTML structure as it is. Because that's how it is implemented in mine project.***

This is simplest implementation of bootstrap button group. See [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/GCUOZpq5iYnhn9fgIbet)

**CODE**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group" style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            11111
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            22222
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            33333
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            44444
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            55555
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            22222
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            33333
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            44444
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            55555
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            44444
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            55555
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `float: left;` as well as add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent. So in your css:

```
.btn-group {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn.btn-primary,
.btn.btn-success {
  float: none;
}
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lRWyHeeN78d2sSNaXGSZ?p=preview

Although, I would recommend adding a specific class to the btn-group/btn-primary/btn-success because overriding bootstraps styling instead of just adding a custom class is a bad practice.

For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group custom-class">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary custom-class">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success custom-class">
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group.custom-class{...}
.btn.btn-primary.custom-class,
.btn.btn-success.custom-class {...}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/nAZD6Hssgnep37fXU9vb?p=preview

Comment: how come some white space coming in between? you can update the answer with adding new class if that is good practise.

Comment: Add `font-size: 0;` to `.btn-group` or `.btn-group.custom-class` (of course rename 'custom-class' to something more specific)

Answer (score 1):

Try display:inline-flex on parent instead on display:inline-block on btn-group

```
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well form-horizontal" style="">
    <div class="form-group" style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <div>
        <div class="btn-group" style="display:inline-flex;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            11111
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            22222
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            33333
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            44444
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            55555
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            22222
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            33333
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            44444
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            55555
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            44444
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            55555
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```